# ag-grid table data convert to json and post to server on data dragged or clicked from pivot

Tags: javascript

ag-grid table data convert to json and post to server on data dragged or clicked from pivot . 
I needed to get the table data in json when items are selected or dragged from pivot  . 
Needed to post the data everytime such action happens

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Sir , By the use of ag-grid i wish to get the json file of the table , the json file will be every time refersh due to data dragging from the pivot so it should update the backend . The data update to backend will happen in json format so i need the json every time data is dragged to the table from pivot .

Comment: How have you tried to accomplish it?

Comment: i didn't get any resource to get the concept , if you could help me show it in a demo at plunker json in an alert box i would be very greatful